# Wordpress different header image for each page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My theme doesn't support custom headers when trying via a plugin so i was wondering if there was another way around this?

Tested WP Header Images by adding some code in header.php, but doesn't seem to work.

Tried the plugin Unique Headers, but it pops a message that the theme doesn't provide custom header when activating it.

Comment: Can you not just target the background image of your header by the unique class on any WordPress page?

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is the same header for every WordPress page of the site. But how to call different header in WordPress? For that, create a new header-your page.php file i.e create a header file for the page you want a different header. Suppose you want a different header on about page. Create a header-about.php file and keep it in the Theme folder.

Then, go in page template file say page.php and replace the header code with

```
<?php
if(is_page(about))
{
get_header('about');
}
else
{
get_header();
}
wp_head();
?>
```

You can see, is_page is used to check the page id for “about” page. The function get_header is used for calling a new header file. Simply, the above code is informing WordPress that if someone opens the page, which is ‘about’ then WordPress will display a file called header-about.php if it is existing. If not, then WordPress will render the default header file.

This way, you can call different WordPress headers on different pages.